# How to load a user-specific file from within a node module?

Tags: javascript, node.js, module

I am creating a node module that applications can import (via npm install). A function within my module will accept the location of a .json file that is set in the users' application (as specified by `filePath` below):

```
...
function (filePath){
    messages = jsonfile.readFileSync(filePath);
}
...
```

How do I allow my function to accept this file path and process it in a way that my module will be able to find it, given that my function will never know where the users' application file will be stored?

Comment: Require it to be a full path? The application can just pass `path.join(__dirname, …)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're writing a node library then your module will be `require`d by the user's application and thus saved in the `node_modules` folder. The thing to notice is that your code just becomes code run in the user's application, therefore paths will be relative to the user's application.

For example: Let's make two modules, `echo-file` and `user-app` with their own folders and their own `package.json`s as their own projects. Here is a simple folder structure with two modules.

```
workspace
|- echo-file
  |- index.js
  |- package.json
|- user-app
  |- index.js
  |- package.json
  |- userfile.txt
```

---

## `echo-file` module

`workspace/echo-file/package.json`

```
{
  "name": "echo-file",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {"test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"},
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

`workspace/echo-file/index.js` (the entry point of your module)

```
const fs = require('fs');
// module.exports defines what your modules exposes to other modules that will use your module
module.exports = function (filePath) {
    return fs.readFileSync(filePath).toString();
}
```

---

## `user-app` module

NPM allows you to install packages from folders. It will copy the local project into your `node_modules` folder and then the user can `require` it.

After initializing this npm project, you can `npm install --save ../echo-file` and that will add it as a dependency to the user's application.

`workspace/user-app/package.json`

```
{
  "name": "user-app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {"test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"},
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "echo-file": "file:///C:\\Users\\Rico\\workspace\\echo-file"
  }
}
```

`workspace/user-app/userfile.txt`

```
hello there
```

`workspace/user-app/index.js`

```
const lib = require('echo-file'); // require
console.log(lib('userfile.txt')); // use module; outputs `hello there` as expected
```

> How do I allow my function to accept this file path and process it in a way that my module will be able to find it, given that my function will never know where the users' application file will be stored?

**So long story short: file paths will be relative to the user's app folder.**

When your module is `npm install`ed, it copies to `node_modules`. When a file path is given to your module, it will be relative to the project. Node follows the [`commonJS` module definition](http://know.cujojs.com/tutorials/modules/authoring-cjs-modules). [EggHead also has a good tutorial](https://egghead.io/lessons/nodejs-commonjs-basics-introduction) on it.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

how about use absolute path ?

if you write in `yourapp/lib/index.js.`

```
path.join(__dirname, '../../../xx.json');
```